# iOS Installed constraints changed after rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, autolayout

I spent last couple days on figuring out constraints issue, but I got no where and would love to get some helps. Basically I want a subview is centered horizontally with some fixed width, but no more than its parent view size (which is a hardcode value but will change when we rotate)

some constraints are installed, some are not. I try to understand why.

Here are examples of horizontal constraints, I ignore most of vertical constraints.

```
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationLessThanOrEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];

_containerViewWidthConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:[self getWidth]];
[_containerView addConstraint:_containerView];
[_containerView constrainToSuperviewCenterX]; // custom function to center X
```

[image]

When I launch the page in portrait, initially only center and width constraints are installed, trailing and leading are not.

When I rotate to landscape, width and constraints are installed, everything looks correct. I do not know why trailing and leading are not installed, but I assume it is necessary.
[image: Correct landscape rotation]

When I rotate back to portrait, well installed constraints changed, width is not installed anymore. UI still looks correctly.

[image]
[image]

But when I rotate back to landscape, UI will look wrong
Its width is still 375, even though I updated width constraint to 812, but it is not installed

[image: incorrect constraint, width constraint is not installed]

Here is how I update my width constraint

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    _containViewWidthConstraint.constant = [self getWidth]; // subclass will provide its width, for this subclass, we provide screen width
}
```

I tried couple things

1. Lower width constraint priority, then everything is screwed up (subview becomes very narrow, so it looks even wrong in portrait)
2. Remove trailing and leading constraints, everything works fine, but we lost the max cap

Answer (score 0):

Interesting enough there is nothing to do with this view, actually in my subview, I have another constraint for a button, which breaks this view's constraint

Comment: Is this the answer? Can this Question-and-Answer now be completed, with this as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

If it helps try to give them width and height related to the superView like width of your view is = 0.7 from the width of the superView